# R: one-dimensional optimization

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to use `optimize()`, or something similar, to search for a minimum / maximum value of a function. However I am unsure of about the exact range over which the function should be optimized, which is a required parameter for the function 'optimze()' (e.g. `optimize(f=FUN,interval=c(lowerBound,upperBound))`).

In this optimization problem, I am able to estimate a value `a` that is "close" to the optimal solution, but "closeness" depends on the situation.

Is there a function in R that can use the initial value `a` that does not require that the interval over which the function is optimized to be specified up front?

Comment: How about `my_optimize = function(f, a) {optimize(f = f, interval = c(a - 100, a + 100))}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say you're not sure about the lower limit, I suspect that this means that the parameter you are trying to estimate is not bounded below.

If this the case, one trick is to transform the function so that there is a lower bound on the parameter.

This trivial function has a minimum at x=4:

```
fun <- function(x) -exp(-(x - 4)^2) + 8
```

which we can find via:

```
optimize(f=fun,interval=c(0,8))
#> $minimum
#> [1] 4
```

but let's pretend for a moment that we're not sure if there is a lower limit or not, and that we know that the upper limit is 8.  R will throw an error if we try:

```
optimize(f=fun,interval=c(-Inf,8))
```

because the bounds must be finite.  In this case, we can use the exponential transformation (`exp()`) which maps 
the real numbers to the positive numbers, like so:

```
optimize(f=function(x)fun(log(x)),
         interval=exp(c(-Inf,8)))
#> $minimum
#> [1] 54.59815
```

and then to get the root, you just need to back transform the above the solution via:

```
log(54.59815)
#> 4
```

If you don't know either the upper or lower bound on the underlying parameter, then you can use the log-odds transformation in place of the `log()`:

```
function(x) log(x/(1-x))
```

and it's inverse in place of `exp()`:

```
function(y) exp(y)/(1 + exp(y))
```

Note that the log-odds transformation maps the real numbers onto the unit interval, so the interval parameter becomes `0:1`.

These solutions do have some numerical limitations (e.g. if we had set `interval=exp(c(-Inf,16))` in the first solution, we would have gotten an error).  Tip, you can re-scale these transformations to center around a given point `a` which can reduce the numerical limitations.

Comment: Good info. These transform/untransform operations would also affect the specified tolerance (`tol=`), which determines the accuracy of the optimisation. Might have to adjust for that.

Comment: Yes, Absolutely.  That is one of those 'limitiations' that I glossed over.

Comment: One trick is to use the transform / back-transform schema to get a reasonably close guess and then re-estimate without the transformation with a interval that is several times the tolerance times wider the first derivative of the transformation at the estimated maxima/minima.